# When and why is updateConstraints called?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit

When and why is updateConstraints called? And when overriding, what kind work is meant to be done in the override?

I've read and watched lots of information on how Auto Layout works, but i can't seem wrap my head around it completely.

Do you update the constant of any special interest constraints you saved references to, or to do customising do you remove all constraints from your view and recreate them entirely like one guy did in a WWDC video?

Answer (score 5):

Some thoughts about the matter are to be found here:

```
https://oleb.net/blog/2015/08/how-to-use-updateconstraints/
```

And of course there is occasional information on this topic in WWDC videos.

But on the whole the answer is probably: don't override `updateConstraints`. It isn't called very often under normal circumstances, so you'd only need to override it if you were also calling `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`, and the result is probably an unnecessarily confusing and elaborate architecture. There is generally no need for an `updateConstraints` override. The WWDC 2018 video on auto layout shows that such overrides are often written incorrectly and just cause a bunch of highly inefficient layout "churn". If you need to change constraints, just change them at the point where the need for the change arises.

As the documentation now says:

> It is almost always cleaner and easier to update a constraint immediately after the affecting change has occurred. For example, if you want to change a constraint in response to a button tap, make that change directly in the button’s action method.
>   You should only override *this* method when changing constraints in place is too slow, or when a view is producing a number of redundant changes.

That last sentence refers to a situation that is extraordinarily rare, and in any case you're unlikely to know what to do to implement `updateConstraints` properly to gain efficiency. So don't.